# Django views: Using a queryset with exclude after a for loop

Tags: python, django, django-views

in my views.py I have a queryset (bytes) that I loop through, adding a `style` property to certain items in the queryset:

```
bytes = Byte.objects.order_by('-publish_date')

for d in bytes:
  if not d.published:
    d.style = 'my-style'
```

Then in my views, I have another conditional statement:

```
if most_recent != most_shared:
    bytes = bytes.exclude(byte_id=most_shared_id)
```

But then when I sent `bytes` to the template, none of the info from the loop (if any item in the `bytes` got `d.style`) is there. How can I make this so when I use exclude I'm doing so on the `bytes` that just went through the loop??

Comment: That would be easier if you showed the full view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the property via an annotation using a [conditional expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/conditional-expressions/)

```
from django.db.models import Case, CharField, Value, When

queryset = Byte.objects.annotate(
    style=Case(
        When(published=False, then=Value('my-style')),
        default=Value(''),
        output_field=CharField()
    )
).order_by('-publish_date')

if most_recent != most_shared:
    queryset = queryset.exclude(byte_id=most_shared_id)
```

Since the annotation is part of the query the annotation will persist after any subsequent filters or exclusions

You shouldn't name your variables the same as any built-in functions, you are overriding the built-in function [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-bytes)